# Как передать пропсы через React-router

Tags: reactjs

я использую react-router-dom и компоненты я отрисовываю через Route

```
<Route  path='/profile' component={Profile}/>
```

но мне нужно передать в компонент profile некоторые пропсы, если я делаю вот так:

```
<Route user={this.state} path='/profile' component={Profile}/>}
```

то ничего не получается, подскажите как правильно сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте не `component` а свойство `render`  для того чтобы передать пропсы.

К примеру у вас есть компонент `Greeting`

```
class Greeting extends Component {
  render() {
    const {text, match: {params}} = this.props;

    const {name} = params;

    return (
      <>
        <h1>Greeting page</h1>
        <p>
          {text} {name}
        </p>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Для того чтобы передать ему пропсы через `Router` надо написать так:

```
<Route
    path="/profile/:name"
    render={props => <Greeting text="Hello " {...props} />}
  />
```

Полный код  [**тут**](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-frost-18k4n)